# Ion-gated ion channels

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, biophysics, literature

Today I've heard for the first time of [calcium-gated ion channels](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22calcium%20gated%20ion%20channel%22) but find it hard to get an idea how they work, where they are located, and which role they play.

I assume calcium-gated ion channels are just a special form of ion-gated ion channels, which would be a fourth group of ion channels next to [voltage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage-gated_ion_channel)-, [lipid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipid-gated_ion_channels)-, and [ligand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligand-gated_ion_channel)-gated ion channels (with ligands being some larger molecules). But on [ion-gated ion channels](http://www.google.de/search?q=%22ion%20gated%20ion%20channel%22) even less is to be found on the internet.

One specific paper that mentions ion-gated ion channels is [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11573972) (Experimental Neurology, 2001)

One paper that mentions calcium-gated ion channels is [this](https://www.alchimiaweb.com/blogfr/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Friedman-Devinsky-CBDs-Epi-NEJM-2015-Cannabinoids-in-the-Treatment-of-Epilepsy.pdf) (New England Journal of Medicine, 2015)

Where do I find a general introduction into ion-gated ion channels - if they exist?

Comment: KIR could be considered as a ion gated ion channel. In this case Mg+2 blocks the channel from the inside preventing the "outward" conduction of ions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main families of calcium-gated channels I am aware of are the [calcium-gated potassium channels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium-activated_potassium_channel) and the internal [ryanodine receptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryanodine_receptor) involved in calcium-induced calcium release - you could start from those linked Wikipedia articles.

I wouldn't really make these a fourth category, they should either be thought of as voltage-gated channels that are modulated by intracellular calcium, or as ligand-gated channels - the ligand just happens to be a calcium ion.

Some channels in this category are not influenced by calcium directly but via [calmodulin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calmodulin), which is a common mediator of calcium-driven intracellular influences.

Comment: [Ryanodine receptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryanodine_receptor) is also a good example.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Thanks - added.